# Converting HTML entities to their applicable characters

Tags: php, html

```
$str = '&amp;lt;div style="text-align:center"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;img src="http://image.gif" border="0"&amp;gt;';

echo html_entity_decode($str,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Outputs the same:

```
&lt;div style="text-align:center"&gt;&lt;img src="http://image.gif" border="0"&gt;
```

I'm expecting:

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src="http://image.gif" border="0"></div>
```

Comment: You need to decode twice because `&amp;` needs to decode to `&` in order to get `&lt;` etc...

Comment: I'm using eBay API which returns all description in this format, sometimes even double decoding doesn't convert the entities, is there any reliable way I could do it repeatedly until all entities are converted?

Comment: I'm using eBay API which returns all description in this format, sometimes even double decoding doesn't convert the entities, is there any reliable way I could do it repeatedly until all entities are converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been double encoded, so you need to decode twice as `&amp;` needs to decode to `&` in order to get `&lt;` etc...

```
echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($str));
```

If you are doing the encoding then look at the `$double_encode` parameter for `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`.

If encoded multiple times then you could use:

```
while(($str = html_entity_decode($str)) != $str) {}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "htmlspecialchars_decode()" instead of "html_entity_decode()"

[htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: *The converted entities are: `&amp;`, `&quot;` (when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set), `&#039;` (when ENT_QUOTES is set), `&lt;` and `&gt;`.*

Comment: Tried with and without `ENT_NOQUOTES`, its still the same.

Comment: I did this using my method above in my test environment. The result came out fine. http://www.cardeninteractive.com/test.php